# i can't conect a database in phpmyadmin to a datatable that is making queries server side in wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql

im trying to put a table in a wordpress using datatables. the info is a 50K Row table already in my server, it's data is horrible, it wasn't made to be an efficient database, just an excel but that's what i have to work and remaking the info is not a posibility in the short term (eventually i want to do a proper work with the data). the idea is retrieving the info using ajax and server side queries.

the problem is that the functions.php appears to work but it can't retrieve the information that my veteranos_79.php needs to generate, a json file that datatables transform into a table.

p.d. keep in mind im totally new in this and every advice, even educational material is apreciated. my idea is learning with this too, not just making it work.

i uploaded a database to phpmyadmin, after that i made a file called veteranos_79.php where i conect the database, in functions.php i put the ajax call and server side queries to avoid making the slowest server known to mankind.

the functions.php appears to work but it can't retrieve the information that my veteranos_79.php needs to generate. it needs to generate a json file that datatables transform into a table but when i acces it directly it doesn't work, not even a failed conection. it's like the file is not present at all.

this is the result: veteranos.guerradelpacifico1879.cl

this is my veteranos_79.php:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Configuración de acceso a la base de datos
$servername = "mysql.veteranos.guerradelpacifico1879.cl"; // Cambiar esto si es necesario
$username = "veteranosguerrad";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "veteranos_guerradelpacif";

// Crear la conexión a la base de datos utilizando MySQLi
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Verificar la conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Parámetros recibidos de DataTables
$draw = $_GET['draw'];
$start = $_GET['start'];
$length = $_GET['length'];
$searchValue = '%' . $_GET['search']['value'] . '%'; // Valor de búsqueda proporcionado por el usuario

// Columnas para ordenamiento y llamada ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#miTabla').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/veteranos_79.php' ) ); ?>",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "DIVISION" },
            { "data": "BRIGADA" },
            { "data": "UNIDAD" },
            { "data": "REGIMIENTO" },
            { "data": "COMPANIA" },
            { "data": "CLASE" },
            { "data": "1_NOMBRE" },
            { "data": "2_NOMBRE" },
            { "data": "1_APELLIDO" },
            { "data": "2_APELLIDO" },
            { "data": "NOTAS" },
            { "data": "OTROS" },
            { "data": "BBDD" }
        ]
        // Otras opciones de configuración...
    });
});
// Sentencia SQL base
$sql = "SELECT * FROM BBDD_csv WHERE CONCAT(DIVISION, ' ',BRIGADA, ' ',UNIDAD, ' ',REGIMIENTO, ' ',COMPANIA, ' ',CLASE, ' ',1_NOMBRE, ' ',2_NOMBRE, ' ',1_APELLIDO, ' ',2_APELLIDO, ' ',NOTAS, ' ',OTROS, ' ',BBDD) LIKE ?";

// Si se especificó un valor de búsqueda, agregamos el filtro a la consulta
if (!empty($searchValue)) {
    $sql .= " AND CONCAT(DIVISION, ' ',BRIGADA, ' ',UNIDAD, ' ',REGIMIENTO, ' ',COMPANIA, ' ',CLASE, ' ',1_NOMBRE, ' ',2_NOMBRE, ' ',1_APELLIDO, ' ' ,2_APELLIDO, ' ',NOTAS, ' ',OTROS, ' ',BBDD) LIKE ?";
}

// Obtener el número total de registros sin aplicar el límite y el filtro de búsqueda
$stmtTotal = $conn->prepare($sql);
if (!empty($searchValue)) {
    $stmtTotal->bind_param("ss", "%$searchValue%", "%$searchValue%");
} else {
    $stmtFiltered->bind_param("s", $searchValue);
}
$stmtTotal->execute();
$totalRecords = $stmtTotal->get_result()->num_rows;
$stmtTotal->close();

// Agregar la cláusula ORDER BY para el ordenamiento
$orderColumnIndex = $_GET['order'][0]['column']; // Índice de la columna a ordenar
$orderDirection = $_GET['order'][0]['dir']; // Dirección del ordenamiento (ascendente o descendente)
$sql .= " ORDER BY " . $columns[$orderColumnIndex] . " " . $orderDirection;

// Agregar la cláusula LIMIT para la paginación
$sql .= " LIMIT $start, $length";

// Obtener el número de registros filtrados (para paginación)
$stmtFiltered = $conn->prepare($sql);
if (!empty($searchValue)) {
    $stmtFiltered->bind_param("ss", "%$searchValue%", "%$searchValue%");
} else {
    $stmtFiltered->bind_param("s", $searchValue);
}
$stmtFiltered->execute();
$totalRecordsFiltered = $stmtFiltered->get_result()->num_rows;
$stmtFiltered->close();

// Ejecutar la consulta para obtener los datos
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Crear el arreglo de datos en el formato requerido por DataTables
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

// Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
$conn->close();

// Crear el arreglo de respuesta
$response = array(
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "recordsTotal" => $totalRecords,
    "recordsFiltered" => $totalRecordsFiltered,
    "data" => $data
);

// Devolver los datos en formato JSON
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

this is functions.php:

```
<?php
function mi_tabla_datatables_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="miTabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DIVISION</th>
                    <th>BRIGADA</th>
                    <th>UNIDAD</th>
                    <th>REGIMIENTO</th>
                    <th>COMPANIA</th>
                    <th>CLASE</th>
                    <th>1_NOMBRE</th>
                    <th>2_NOMBRE</th>
                    <th>1_APELLIDO</th>
                    <th>2_APELLIDO</th>
                    <th>NOTAS</th>
                    <th>OTROS</th>
                    <th>BBDD</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Los datos de la tabla serán obtenidos a través de DataTables -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <?php
    // Cargamos la versión de jQuery incluida con WordPress
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // Cargamos el script de DataTables
    wp_enqueue_script('datatables', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.5/b-2.4.1/b-colvis-2.4.1/fc-4.3.0/fh-3.4.0/r-2.5.0/sc-2.2.0/datatables.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.13.5', true);

    // Retornamos el código JavaScript del shortcode
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#miTabla').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/veteranos_79.php' ) ); ?>",
                "type": "GET"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "DIVISION" },
                { "data": "BRIGADA" },
                { "data": "UNIDAD" },
                { "data": "REGIMIENTO" },
                { "data": "COMPANIA" },
                { "data": "CLASE" },
                { "data": "1_NOMBRE" },
                { "data": "2_NOMBRE" },
                { "data": "1_APELLIDO" },
                { "data": "2_APELLIDO" },
                { "data": "NOTAS" },
                { "data": "OTROS" },
                { "data": "BBDD" }
            ]
            // Otras opciones de configuración...
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('mi_tabla_datatables', 'mi_tabla_datatables_shortcode');
```

i have a friends version of the same text but i prefer the feedback of my work even if it has more problems.